# Li-ion battery charging circuit issue

Tags: battery-charging, hardware, static-electricity

[image: Used Schematic for Li-Ion Battery Charging in my project]

I have added a Li-ion battery charging circuit to my project for powering up the whole circuit by taking reference from [this site](https://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/tp4056.html).

The issue I am facing here is maybe related to static charges.

When I connect the battery the circuit doesn't power up, but when I touch the surface of the circuit where IC DW01A is placed, the circuit does power up and works fine for days, but the same issue repeats again.

I have tested this with different ICs and different circuits with the same schematic and I face the same issue.

Has anyone faced this issue? Or does anyone know what's actually happening and what I should do to avoid this?

Comment: I don't see any mechanism on your schematic for the battery to provide power to anything. How is it connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much of testing, trials and looking into forums I did find the issue and the solution as well. The problem wasn't with the circuit or component values, but it's the way IC DW01A is designed to work.

I used to replace the batteries from the circuit. That is, my circuits were kept idle without the batteries in it and when I wanted to use one, I used to place the battery and try to turn the circuit on and, as stated, I wasn't able to turn it on.

But, then I found that the IC DW01A needs a kickstart to work properly whenever it loses power (i.e. VCC given to IC).

Kickstart can be done by connecting the charging source (USB supply) to the circuit with the battery connected. And after a kickstart, as long as we aren't replacing the batteries, the circuit will be able to charge and discharge normally.

If we replace the batteries for some reason, we need to kickstart the IC again. This is what I found so far and my circuits are working fine with this logic.

Hope this helps if someone is going through the same.

Answer (score 2):

The chip does not turn on entirely unless you connect the charger once. It does not come out of its hibernation mode.

When you touch the chip you're charging the gates of the MOSFETs. This turns it on until the charge is depleted.

Please try connecting it once to a charger, with a battery connected.

Comment: You are right, the circuit does power up when we connect the charger with a battery. But this isn't ideal for every run. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

When I hear something turns on or off by touching it, a lot of times that means something is floating. It appears that when Q1 is off, the battery will be floating in reference to ground. Because of this, the CS pin may be reading a voltage that is above the 150 mV threshold which will shut it down. Once you get it to turn on, the B- is no longer floating and will keep itself on.

My suggestion would be to try and connect a large value resistor between GND and the negative of the battery. I'd try somewhere between 100-470 kΩ and see what happens.

Comment: Makes sense. I am on it. I will let you know if it works. Thank you.

Comment: I tested the circuit by adding resistor as you suggested but still no change. The circuit behaves the same as before.